# Upgrading Elasticsearch 2.1.1 to 2.2.0 - missing authentication token?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-shield

I decided to try upgrade the current cluster from ES2.1.1 to ES2.2.0.
A mirror pair. The cluster is running within AWS, so I'm using the `cloud-aws` plugin for communication.

I successfully upgraded the first node, and it has assumed master status, but I have encountered a strange communication/authentication issue when upgrading the second node.

I paid attention to the guidelines [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/rolling-upgrades.html), but I still seem to be experiencing a strange issue.

From main cluster log on 2nd node:

```
[2016-02-03 12:29:41,241][INFO ][discovery.ec2            ] [Sharon Ventura] failed to send join request to master [{Space Phantom}{NzN7b7ZHT8uPu6oXJAORMg}{10.60.164.147}{10.60.164.147:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Space Phantom][10.60.164.147:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[failure when sending a validation request to node]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[Sharon Ventura][10.60.163.74:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; ]
[2016-02-03 12:29:42,455][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.health] [Sharon Ventura] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2016-02-03 12:29:44,255][INFO ][discovery.ec2            ] [Sharon Ventura] failed to send join request to master [{Space Phantom}{NzN7b7ZHT8uPu6oXJAORMg}{10.60.164.147}{10.60.164.147:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Space Phantom][10.60.164.147:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[failure when sending a validation request to node]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[Sharon Ventura][10.60.163.74:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; ]
[2016-02-03 12:29:47,269][INFO ][discovery.ec2            ] [Sharon Ventura] failed to send join request to master [{Space Phantom}{NzN7b7ZHT8uPu6oXJAORMg}{10.60.164.147}{10.60.164.147:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Space Phantom][10.60.164.147:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[failure when sending a validation request to node]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[Sharon Ventura][10.60.163.74:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; ]
[2016-02-03 12:29:49,472][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [Sharon Ventura] timed out while retrying [cluster:monitor/state] after failure (timeout [30s])
[2016-02-03 12:29:49,473][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /_cluster/settings Params: {}
MasterNotDiscoveredException[null]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$5.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:205)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:794)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-02-03 12:29:50,283][INFO ][discovery.ec2            ] [Sharon Ventura] failed to send join request to master [{Space Phantom}{NzN7b7ZHT8uPu6oXJAORMg}{10.60.164.147}{10.60.164.147:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Space Phantom][10.60.164.147:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalStateException[failure when sending a validation request to node]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[Sharon Ventura][10.60.163.74:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [internal:discovery/zen/join/validate]]; ]
```

My elasticsearch.yml file:

```
cluster.name: cluster01
http.cors.enabled: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: ec2
discovery.ec2.tag.project_code_info: "cluster01"
cloud.aws.region: eu-central-1
```

I can see in the logs that it has detected the 1st node: `[Space Phantom][10.60.164.147:9300]`
It has detected it without any intervention, but it apparently cannot authenticate.

I suspect this may be related to the `Shield` plugin, which is installed also, but the correct and identical permissions are setup the same as before. Nothing else has changed.

I'm using a username and password in shield, no SSL configured.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, as @user3458016 requested.

I managed to resolve this issue, by (**on all nodes**) resetting all settings and configurations, removing plugins `license`, `shield`, removing all users and re-adding all of them as before. These configurations were identical to begin with, so this is odd.

First, stop elasticsearch on all nodes.
Stop kibana if running locally.

**If you have any custom roles**, check the configuration of this in `/etc/elasticsearch/shield/roles.yml`
refresh this from a single recorded configuration if possible.

remove plugins:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin remove elasticsearch/license/latest`
`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin remove elasticsearch/shield/latest`

remove users:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers userdel admin`
`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers userdel logstash`

re-add plugins:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install elasticsearch/license/latest -b`
`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install elasticsearch/shield/latest -b`

re-add users:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd admin -p adminuserpw -r admin`
`/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd logstash -p logstashuserpw -r logstash`

**If you have any custom roles**, double-check the configuration of this in `/etc/elasticsearch/shield/roles.yml` to verify the configuration is not been modified or over-written.

Start elasticsearch on **first node**.
Start kibana if running locally.

Check indices have come up correctly and **verify master node status**.

***Do all the above steps on all other nodes.***

Start elasticsearch on remaining nodes, **one at a time**.
Verify healthy cluster replication before starting next node.

I hope someone finds this useful.